# Watch order for the Netflix Witcher series

Tags: tv, suggested-order, the-witcher

I noticed that in addition to season 2 of the show, Netflix is currently promoting other supplemental material as well. I don't know what I ought to watch and when I ought to watch it.

Not counting the season 1 recap, the making of, or inside the episodes features, **what should I watch and in what order?**

Content I currently see:

- Season 1
- Season 2
- The Witcher: Fireplace
- The Witcher: Bestiary Part 1
- The Witcher: Bestiary Part 2
- The Witcher: Nightmare of the Wolf
- The Witcher: Characters of the Continent
- The Witcher: Blood Origin

I could see the characters and bestiary stuff being extremely helpful to understanding what's going on during season 1 and 2, for example, but I don't want to spoil anything for myself.

Comment: AFAIA _The Witcher's Bestiary_ and _Characters of the Continent_ are out of universe information videos so not really needed. I'm not too sure but I have a feeling that Fireplace is literally just that. Nightmare of the Wolf is a prequel focusing on Vesemir and Blood Origin is a prequel series focusing on the elves which is not yet out yet. So as far as the series goes they can all be ignored. I've not watched any of the extra content though so commenting for now.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Yeah I want to watch the bestiary stuff specifically but I'm worried about it giving away spoiler-ish info from more of an epilogue perspective. Like "Here's the beasts you saw and here's why they did that thing to that character you liked."

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Sometimes a monster is *supposed* to be a surprise and figuring out what it is and how it operates is literally the entire plot of an episode. So I don't want to ruin that for myself. But when Geralt is chatting it up with another witcher and they start reminiscing about the time they teamed up to fight a wyvern or whatever, I'd like to get the reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only *need* to watch the main series i.e. the 8 episodes in each season. Everything else is supplementary information. Going through the extra content available that you mention though:

- *The Witcher: Fireplace*: This is quite literally what is says on the tin, just a fire place. Watch it whenever (I don't see why you would though!). However, it is at Kaer Morhen so if you want to avoid spoilers for what that looks like wait until it's introduced later on in season 2.
- *The Witcher: Bestiary*: The full names for this is actually *The Witcher Bestiary Season 1* and it is available in 2 parts. As such it only goes over monsters in the first season. You are fine to watch it after the first season to avoid spoilers.
- *The Characters of the Continent*: I've not watched it yet but this appears to go over characters in the series including those in series 2. To be safe from spoilers you probably want to watch it after season 2.
- *The Witcher: Nightmare of the Wolf*: This is an animated spin off focusing on a younger Vesemir. It isn't necessary to watch but watching it in release order should be fine so after season 1 and before season 2. Though you may wish to watch it at any time.
- *The Witcher: Blood Origin*: This is going to be a mini-series spinoff focusing on the first of the Witchers. It's not out yet so we can't say for certain but it is likely not necessary to watch. I'd probably watch it in release order so probably after season 2 and before season 3 but as above I imagine it can be watched at any time or not at all.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Many conflate Season 1’s non-sequential chronology of events to some desire for a “viewing order” for episodes of Season 1, but that’s folly. Unless you have esoteric personal reasons for doing so, you should just watch Season 1 in episode order, then Season 2 the same way. This will allow you the best viewing experience as the shows’ creators intended; although some viewers may have different goals for their own viewing pleasure than that. And that’s great too.

Comment: I just watched the bestiary features. Yeah, they're spoilerish and don't add a ton to the experience. Definitely something to be left until after season 1 for some out of universe history.